# Contains MySQL function - unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, contains, spatial, contain

I am using `MySQL 5.5.35` server on `Debian 7 x86_64`. I am trying to check if the point is within the rectangle. I use the `Contains` function this way:

```
SELECT Contains
(
    Polygon
    (
        Point(55.538322,37.332026),
        Point(55.566347,37.875850),
        Point(55.898002,37.873103),
        Point(55.896459,37.381465),
        Point(55.538322,37.332026)
    ),
    Point(55.737177,37.623164)
)
```

The point is obviously within the rectangle and I was expecting to get the `1` output, but what I am getting is `(NULL)`.

Could you please point me my mistake? Thank you!

**Update:** after some debug it comes out the the `NULL` is return by the `Polygon` function. So that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-spatial-values.html#function_polygon) I'ver found out that the `Polygon` function expects it's parameters to be of type `LineString`. The correct example is:

```
SELECT
Contains
(
   Polygon
   (
        LineString
        (
          Point(55.538322,37.332026),
          Point(55.566347,37.875850),
          Point(55.898002,37.873103),
          Point(55.896459,37.381465),
          Point(55.538322,37.332026)
        )
    ),
    Point(55.737177,37.623164)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this sintax

```
SELECT
MBRContains(
    GeomFromText('Polygon((55.538322 37.332026,55.566347 37.87585,55.898002 37.873103,55.896459 37.381465,55.538322 37.332026))'),
    GeomFromText('Point(55.737177 37.623164)'));
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. The syntax you have suggested does work for me. Maybe you know why mine does not work? Thank you!

Comment: Sincerely I think that for spatial relations you need to use precise functions (MBRContains and not just contains) just as explained on the mysql dev site 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html
For the rest I don't know why doesn't works without the 'GeomFromText' keyword, but I've always used this sintax getting it from the Mysql site.

Comment: I've found out what my error was and posted the answer which may be useful to someone else.